# Flutter: Long text inside stack overlaps & starts from the top

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to wrap long text inside `Text` widget, stacked inside a `Stack`. Following is the code.

```
Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          _header(context),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment(0.0, -0.5),
            child: Text(
                "TITLE OF LONG TEXT",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ),
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.0),
              child:  Text(
                "text long. " * 150,
              )
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

The problem is that the text is overlapping and starts from the top of the view. As seen here:

[Screenshot of the overlapping text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYuXT.png)

What am I doing wrong? I tried using ListView inside the stack, which also results in the same issue.

Comment: How do you want it to look?

Comment: That the "text long" text to start below the Title text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `Column` instead of `Stack` and `Expanded` (if needed)

```
Column(
  children: []
)
```

Comment: This worked. I used `Column` instead of `Stack` and then added a `ListView` as one of it's child wrapped in `Expanded`. And added `Text` as it's child.